# Loading local CSS file in WebView.replaceContent

Tags: java, javascript, webview, javafx

I'm trying to implement a code editor in JavaFx using

https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/1463485

but the issue is that it downloads the CSS/Javascript from the internet to load CodeMirror. Is there a way to download those files and put them so that it can load them locally on Netbeans? I'm experienced with Java but not so much JavaFX or HTML.

I

Answer (score 0):

Please put the CSS/Javascript in the classpath and use the following code:

```
private final String editingTemplate =
"<!doctype html>" +
"<html>" +
"<head>" +
" <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"codemirror.css\">" +
" <script src=\"codemirror.js\"></script>" +
" <script src=\"clike.js\"></script>" +
"</head>" +
"<body>" +
"<form><textarea id=\"code\" name=\"code\">\n" +
"${code}" +
"</textarea></form>" +
"<script>" +
" var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById(\"code\"), {" +
" lineNumbers: true," +
" matchBrackets: true," +
" mode: \"text/x-java\"" +
" });" +
"</script>" +
"</body>" +
"</html>";
```

I am just trying to pick the CSS/Javascript from the classpath instead of the internet